# How to make custom images for MAAS?

Tags: maas

I installed MAAS 2.0 (rc2+bzr5156) on Ubuntu 16.04. There are only two OS (Ubuntu and CentOS) on the MAAS official mirrors. And the mirrors is not the type of ISO. From the MAAS DOC, I also can not find information about how to custom images for MAAS (only the "import images" information). I find the maas-image-builder, but this tool has been deprecated.

Three questions:

1. Can MAAS support other operating systems like RedHat and Windows? (I cannot find the OS support information from MAAS DOC.)
2. How does MAAS design the image? Is it different from the operating system which is deployed by ISO image?
3. What is the advantage of the MAAS official images, rather than the ISO images?

Answer (score 1):

If possible you should updated to MAAS 2.1 which is available in 16.04 updates, as it supports CentOS by default.

MAAS can support CentOS and Windows, but Windows is not available by default, this is something that you need to buy a support contract for.

There is a technical difference between how MAAS (via a piece of software called curtin) installs Ubuntu. It directly unpacks a root tar file onto the disk, and is quite fast.

Can you clarify what it is you want to do exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
I want to find a tool that can install different kinds of operation systems,such as CentOS, Windows, SUSE, etc. The Windows and CentOS are necessary. So  I need to know that what kind of operation system that MAAS can support. How MAAS installed them. Is it different form the system deployed by a ISO image. I mean that if MAAS adds its own plugin or other software when deploying system. If I need to deploy Windows. do I need contact Ubuntu for a support?

Comment: @Juken The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.